# Ball falling plot of position over time with python

Tags: python, arrays, plot, scatter, kinematics

I am trying to write a code that will plot the the simulation of a ball being dropped from a height h and make a graph of the position over time using the kinematic equations y = y_0 
My code is this:

from matplotlib.pylab import show, xlabel, ylabel, scatter, plot
from numpy import empty

```
def drop():

    """
    This function calculates and creates arrays for the velocity at eac time interval as well as the position and plots it. Assuming no drag. 
    """
    #Define the constants in the problem
    h_0 = 10
    g = -9.8 #gravitational constant N
    dt = 0.1 #timestep

    #Now need to create arrays to hold the positins, time, and velocities
    vel = empty(1000,float)
    time = empty(1000,float)
    y = empty(1000,float)

    time[0] = 0
    vel[0] = 0
    y[0] = h_0

    #code for the kinematic equations for the calculation of time, velocity and position
    for i in range of (1000-1):
        time[i+1] = time[i] + dt
        vel[i+1] = vel[i] + (g * dt)
        y[i+1] = time[i] + (vel[i+1] * dt)

        if y[i] > 0:
        #ensures that the graph will not keep going when the ball hits the ground
            break


    plot(time,y, '.')
    xlabel("Time(s)")
    ylabel("Position")
    show()
```

However my graph plots three dots one in each corner of the graph when it is supposed to look like a curve, and my graph changes every time which it shouldn't since none of the variables are changing

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's get the syntax error out of the way. `for i in range of (1000-1)` is actually `for i in range(1000-1)`, but I assume that was a typo from your part since you could get the code running.

Now, your equations of motion are wrong.

```
y[i+1] = time[i] + (vel[i+1] * dt)

# should be
y[i+1] = y[i] + (vel[i] * dt)
```

Your condition to exit the simulation is also flawed.

```
if y[i] > 0:

# you have to stop when the height becomes until negative
if y[i+1] < 0:
```

Your mistakes so far mean you'll exit the loop after one iteration, having effectively not altered your `y` array. The final problem kicks in here. `numpy.empty()` creates an array without initialising the values. This means that the original values will be whatever resides in memory at that point. If you print `y` after breaking the loop, you may notice most values being 0, while some being very small, but not close to 0, e.g. 3.18377034e-308. Since they are the highest values in your array, they will scale your plot to their range. But since they are arbitrary values, every time you run the code, it'll produce different numbers.

You have two options to fix this. Either use `numpy.zeros()`, or plot only the first `y[:i]` values, which is the point in the loop you break for hitting the ground.

---

Since we have an analytic solution for the equations in your problem, you can do away with the loops and vectorise everything with arrays. We can solve the displacement equation with respect to t (quadratic) to find out when we will hit the ground. Then we initialise the time array and use it to calculate the displacement (velocity is optional).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def time_to_hit_ground(y0, v0, a):
    discriminant = np.sqrt(v0**2 - 2*a*y0)
    t1 = (-v0 - discriminant) / a
    t2 = (-v0 + discriminant) / a
    if t1 >=0:
        return t1
    return t2

def drop(y0, v0=0.0, dt=0.1, g=-9.8):
    if y0 < 0:
        print('Object is underground.')
        return
    # if you also allow the user to change `dt` and `g` from the arguments,
    # you want to check they have the correct sign.

    t_ground = time_to_hit_ground(y0, v0, g)

    t = np.arange(0, t_ground+dt, dt)
    v = v0 + g * t
    y = y0 + v0 * t + g * t**2 / 2.

    plt.plot(t, y, '.')
    plt.axvline(t_ground, color='g')
    plt.axhline(0, color='g')
    plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
    plt.ylabel('Height (m)')
    plt.show()
```